# Is there a way to do a series of jQuery AJAX calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dependencies, synchronize, series

When submitting a web form, I would like to validate the server-side files listed in the form data (check their formats, essentially, through a set of RESTful scripts running on the server).

I might have two file pathnames, but I could have more.

How do I chain a series of validation AJAX calls, so that, if any one request fails with a non-200 status, the entire chain fails and I (for example) redirect to an informative error page?

In SGE, there is a hold (`-hold_jid`) option that allows a "master" job to succeed or fail based on whether all children jobs complete or fail. I'm wondering if something similar is possible in jQuery, and if there are examples to get me up to speed quickly?

Comment: "non-200 error"? I didn't think that 200 was an error. And what about other non-error responses like 304?

Comment: Sorry, not error code, but status code. I always make that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery 1.5, check out the new [deffered](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/) functionality.  That will allow you to sequence Ajax calls in a pretty elegant manner.

Comment: Is there functionality in 1.4.2? And is there a way to return information from the dependent functions to the `fail` call?

Comment: Short of chaining through callback nesting, I don't know of a way to do it.